# How to drop user defined objects from master database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I had created an `SQL Script` for my project's database i.e. used to create all the tables, constraints, views, stored procedures and functions with some minimal data for creating a fresh database.

But by mistake, I had ran it on the `master` database. So that all of those stuff were created in `master` database.

Now, I want to `drop` all that `user-defined objects` from `master` database.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Modify the same script you used for create, to drop instead and run again in the master db.

Comment: Do you think this is the greatest solution you had done ever? :)

Answer (score 25):

I have just created this Script to create a Script to drop all User Defined Objects in you Master database just test it on Dev server before you execute it on Production server ..

```
SELECT
    'DROP ' + CASE WHEN  type = 'U' THEN 'TABLE '
                   WHEN  type = 'P' THEN 'PROCEDURE '
                   WHEN  type = 'FN'THEN 'FUNCTION '
                   WHEN  type = 'V'THEN 'VIEW ' END
     + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.[name]) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(10)

FROM        master.sys.objects o 
INNER JOIN  master.sys.schemas s ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE o.[is_ms_shipped] <> 1
  AND o.[type] IN ('U','P','FN','V')

-- Results to Text --
```

**Generate Script**

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Test_table1]
GO

DROP PROCEDURE [hr].[usp_Test_Proc1]
GO

DROP VIEW [views].[vw_TestView_1]
GO

DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Test_Proc2]
GO

DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Test_Function_GetList]
GO
```

**Note**

If the generated Script tries to delete a table that is referenced by other table via Foreign Key it will throw an error.

Comment: Ya, It does. But is there any other way that we can just run the script once and it gets deleted?

Comment: Well you are generating the Script in First Go by getting the results in 'To Text' from your SSMS and then just executing the script droppoping/Deleting all the objects, Involves one Copy Paste and thats all. It can be done in one go as well but I am away from computer. Replying from phone its not much of a hassle anyway pal :)

Comment: OK. Thanks for your kind reply. :) Will make some more try to resolve it. If I get success, will post that answer else will mark your answer as true. Up to that I am giving +1 for your king solution. :) Thank you very much..

Comment: I also had to use this code to get the user defined table types `SELECT  'DROP TYPE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) FROM sys.types WHERE is_user_defined = 1`

Comment: Simple. Effective. I think this must be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to this link for scripts for drop constraints and tables. http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10407.delete-user-objects-from-a-database.aspx However, it doesn't work with tables defined in a schema and required me to do some changes. Please find the modified code below:

```
-- DROP Foreign Keys
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @fk_id int, @fk_name nvarchar(500), @parent_id int, @parent_name nvarchar(500), @schema_name nvarchar(500)
declare @sql nvarchar(2000)

DECLARE fk_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [name] as fkname, schema_name([SCHEMA_ID]) as schemaname,object_name(parent_object_id) as parentname
from sys.objects where [type] = 'F'

OPEN fk_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM fk_cursor
INTO @fk_name, @schema_name, @parent_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        SET @sql = N''
        SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema_name + N'].[' + @parent_name + N'] DROP ' + @fk_name
        PRINT @sql
        FETCH NEXT FROM fk_cursor INTO @fk_name, @schema_name, @parent_name
END

CLOSE fk_cursor
DEALLOCATE fk_cursor


-- DROP user tables
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @tbl_name nvarchar(500)


DECLARE tbl_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT schema_name([SCHEMA_ID]) as schemaname, [name]
from sys.objects where [type] = 'U' order by [name]


OPEN tbl_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor
INTO @schema_name, @tbl_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        SET @sql = N'DROP TABLE [' + @schema_name + '].[' + @tbl_name + N'] '
        PRINT @sql    
        FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor INTO @schema_name, @tbl_name

END

CLOSE tbl_cursor
DEALLOCATE tbl_cursor
```

Caution: Please peruse the script before executing it!
Please refer to my blog post on this: http://zen-and-art-of-programming.blogspot.in/2015/04/cleanup-restore-master-database-in-sql.html

Answer (score 3):

### With schema name ;

```
SELECT
'DROP ' +
CASE WHEN  type = 'U'  THEN 'TABLE'
     WHEN  type = 'P'  THEN 'PROCEDURE'
     WHEN  type = 'FN' THEN 'FUNCTION'
     WHEN  type = 'V'  THEN 'VIEW' 
END +
' ' + Quotename(Schema_name(schema_id)) + '.' + Quotename(Name)+ CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.objects
WHERE is_ms_shipped <> 1
AND TYPE IN ('U','P','FN','V')
```